# How can I return ext of files in ckfinder

Tags: ckfinder

I am using [ckfinder](http://docs.cksource.com/CKFinder_2.x) in my project.
How can I access to ext of selected files?

```
function BrowseServer(element) {
    var finder = new CKFinder();
    finder.lang = 'fa';
    finder.selectActionFunction = showFileInfo;
    finder.popup();
}

function showFileInfo(fileUrl, file, files) {
    // some code here
}
```

Is there any options for do this?

Answer (score 0):

From what I have checked file extension is only available in `fileUrl` so it seems the only way of getting to extension of selected file is using string operations e.g.

```
function showFileInfo( fileUrl, data, files )
{   
    console.log(fileUrl.substring(fileUrl.lastIndexOf(".")));   
...
```

NOTE: `files` contains an array of all selected files. Single item contains `url` and an `data` object holding the following proprties: `fileSize`, `fileDate`, `fileUrl` and [selectActionData](http://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder_2.x_api/symbols/CKFinder.config.html#.selectActionData). You can get to every selected file extension there e.g.

```
var url = files[0].url;
console.log(url.substring(url.lastIndexOf(".")));
//or
console.log(files[0].data.fileUrl);
```